# How to define overloaded signatures for a const in typescript?

Tags: typescript, overloading, typing

We can define overloaded functions like this in typescript:

```
function hello(name: number): void;
function hello(name: string): void;
function hello(name: number | string): void {
  // ...
}
```

I tried to define this function as a const, like:

```
const hello = (name: number | string): void => {
  // ...
}
```

But not sure how to declare the overload signatures on it:

```
(name: number): void; 
(name: string): void;
```

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given your [overloaded](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) function statement `hello`, you can discover the type that the compiler infers for it yourself by writing a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) to its type and inspecting with IntelliSense by hovering over it in your IDE:

```
type Hello = typeof hello;
/* type Hello = {
    (name: number): void;
    (name: string): void;
} */
```

Here you can see that `Hello` is considered to be an object type with two [call signatures](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/136f728bb011ecf1bbf0ff2aac6dacc5cb6568cb/doc/spec.md#392-call-signatures), representing the call signatures you declared in your overload list, in the same order.

You can also write an equivalent type as an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of function types:

```
type AlsoHello = ((name: string) => void) & ((name: number) => void);
```

If you have a function types `F1` and `F2`, then `F1 & F2` represents an overloaded function where the `F1` signature is checked before the `F2` signature.  In the (increasingly outdated) [TypeScript spec](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/136f728bb011ecf1bbf0ff2aac6dacc5cb6568cb/doc/spec.md#35-intersection-types) it says:

> While it is generally true that `A & B` is equivalent to `B & A`, the order of the constituent types may matter when determining the call and construct signatures of the intersection type.

In the rest of the answer I'll use the object-type-with-multiple-call-signatures version instead of the intersection-of-arrow-function-signatures version.

---

Anyway, in this *particular* case where both signatures return `void`, you can rewrite `hello` as a `const` with no errors if you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#type-annotations) it with the above type:

```
const helloConst: {
  (name: number): void;
  (name: string): void;
} = (name: number | string): void => {
  // ...
}
```

A caveat in general, though... overloaded function statements are not checked as strictly as the `const` assignment.  Overloaded function statements allow the implementation signature's return type to match a union of the return types of the call signatures, even though this is not safe:

```
function goodbye(name: number): number;
function goodbye(name: string): string;
function goodbye(name: number | string): number | string {
  return typeof name === "number" ? name + 1 : name + "!";
}
```

There's no compiler error in the above.  The implementation of `goodbye()` returns `number | string`, and you could change `typeof name === "number"` to `typeof name !== "number"` and the compiler still wouldn't warn you. This is usually considered a feature and not a bug.

But now if you wrote that as a `const`, you get the error:

```
const goodbyeConst: { // error!
  (name: number): number;
  (name: string): string;
} = (name: number | string): number | string =>
    typeof name === "number" ? name + 1 : name + "!";
// Type '(name: string | number) => string | number' 
// is not assignable to 
// type '{ (name: number): number; (name: string): string; }'.
```

The `const` assignment is checked more strictly, and the compiler (correctly) complains that you can't safely treat a function of type `(name: string | number) => string | number` as a function of type `((name: string) => string) & ((name: number) => number)`.  After all, the implementation could always return `string` which meets the implementation signature but fails to match the `number` call signature.

Anyway the way to proceed in such a case is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) instead of an annotation:

```
const goodbyeConstAssert = ((name: number | string): number | string =>
  typeof name === "number" ? name + 1 : name + "!") as { // no error
    (name: number): number;
    (name: string): string;
  }
```

That compiles without error.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYBt1wBRgIYC2qAXImCAQEaoBOAlKQG5wwAmA3ALABQoksCFBiy5CJRAGcoNGGADmDRMzZde4aPCRpMOfEVLkqtRAB9J02QqYtWiAN49EiAPTPEAOk88Avjx5QATwAHVEQACWE4RABeRECQuGAhHVVnACo44NCwmPtHJ0RRfTIKanprFXynIvEpGXlFZQ4fRDTnP2540IBBdAk4CJ1c7BrSOss6GIA+JRtJgDJC0ZKjemnZtjpVHggEKWSsAGE9qFIHbmq9cUMyxptVS7ExiwaK5u5vYauDUuMzcdeG1s0Rm5ycrg8Xg+HT4GkEcjgcFYlACqGWN1oigxNFUsIESARSJRaO+5nqVjJllx6nxiEJyNR6N+NFMlMB2NZALkeQuiBoqCgIBoSC6iTIYhi0ViACJsdLEAB+cVERAAakQAEZEAYJerpQBCaWqXzcHYnOmIhmoY5gKRnFxuWg0OA0fX5JmrLHMh6FUlcxRc41fJ4rMqcl4Ujn-CPTKqZBJJK6SmVyxXK0LqrU6lV6w2pNwAFSyiAA5MsuazsZMQWzuWZsSWeBCYBIyHAoIg8BIJDA5PhKOhQlAol1S3ZfSGqz9VuwJ8V-c9ybPvCX3B1draO-TiTapN1u7QO7ERqSo7Wvatw+TY7zRYmJVKU8z5Uqk5ntem1YgDdLJl37A6iBOi6bq8o8xRTqGtA+uBtQRgGEY+iajhAA)

Answer (score 9):

You can define type/interface with callable signatures and use it to type the variable:

```
type Hello = {
    (name: number): void,
    (name: string): void,
}

const hello: Hello = (name: number | string): void => {
    // ...
}

hello(1); // ok
hello('1'); // ok

declare const wrong: string | number;
// @ts-expect-error
hello(wrong)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhA28D2UC8UDeAoKuoAoA7AQwFsIAuKQgV1ICMIAnASioDckBLAEwBoceImUpQAzsCZdCAczZROvAQF8sWAMZJCEqAAsEyKnEQp0w8lVoNmUAD7jJ0uR2480APkyDcAeh9QAOiCsVSx9E3wARhYAbig-KCQAazCDJHwAckiM2Pj-ZLUeCHV4YiZoTW1gKAB3Ji0ZKgkpWTtqOkYmGKwEgAFgMQBaCAAPSHVgYaZ6plSIuoaWIA)